# Upload only first chunk of file jquery file upload

Tags: coffeescript, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have integrated blueimp jquery file upload on my ruby app and set maxchuk size to 1MB now I am trying to stop file upload after first chunk upload ( means I need 1MB of file ) with `fileuploadchunkdone` but it not working

code is written in coffeescript

```
.bind 'fileuploadchunkdone', (e, data) ->
        if (!data.jqXHR)
            data.errorThrown = 'abort'
            data._trigger('fail', e, data)
        else 
            data.jqXHR.abort()
```

is it possible to stop all uploads after uploading first chunk